# RedirecToAction always sending me back to Default page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I have a project that I've made a handful of major changes. Of course this worked before but I've broken something since then. I did a compare and I cannot find what I broke to cause this.

This is the method that I'm in:

```
public ActionResult Logon2(LogOnModel model)
{
  var control = Logging.StartLog();
  control.ClassName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

  try
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "Starting Logon2");
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "corpid: " + CurrentCustomerSession.Current.CorporationId);
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "model.UserName: " + model.UserName);
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "model.Password: " + model.Password);

    Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("ModelState.IsValid: {0}", ModelState.IsValid));
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
      {
        Logging.WriteLog(control, "Validated User");
        Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("model.UserName: {0}", model.UserName));

        Logging.WriteLog(control, "Start GetCustomerForAccount(model.UserName)");
        var svc = new SubService();
        var customer = svc.GetCustomerForAccount(model.UserName, CurrentCustomerSession.Current.CorporationId);

        // ********** NO ACCOUNTS FOUND ************
        // No customers assigned to this login
        // take them to the add account screen
        if (customer == null)
        {
          // no accounts tied to this logon
          Logging.WriteLog(control, "No accounts found for this login.");
          Logging.WriteLog(control, "RedirectToAction(AddCustomer, Customer)");
          // we need to make sure the branch account number is blank from any prior visits
          CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountGuid = Guid.Empty;
          CurrentCustomerSession.Current.Branch = string.Empty;
          CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountNumber = string.Empty;
          return RedirectToAction("AddCustomer", "Customer");
        }

        Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("customer.AccountId: {0}", customer.AccountId));
        Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("customer.Branch: {0}", customer.Branch));
        Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("customer.AccountNumber: {0}", customer.AccountNumber));

        CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountGuid = Guid.Parse(customer.AccountId);
        CurrentCustomerSession.Current.Branch = customer.Branch;
        CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber;
        CurrentCustomerSession.Current.Name = customer.Name;
        CurrentCustomerSession.Current.PhoneNumber = string.Format("({0}) {1}", customer.AreaCode, customer.PhoneNumber);

        model.AccountId = customer.AccountId;

        // only 1 account tied to this logon
        return RedirectToAction("AccountScreen", "Customer");
      }
      else
      {
        var user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
        if (user != null && user.IsLockedOut)
        {
          const string lockedmsg = "This account has been locked due to too many login attempts. Please reset your password to unlock this account.";
          Logging.WriteLog(control, lockedmsg);
          ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, lockedmsg);
        }

        if (user != null && !user.IsApproved)
        {
          const string lockedmsg =
            "This account has been registered but the email that was sent was never authenticated. Please check your email account for this email.";
          Logging.WriteLog(control, lockedmsg);
          ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, lockedmsg);
        }
        else
        {
          const string msg = "Invalid username or password.";
          Logging.WriteLog(control, msg);
          ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, msg);
        }
      }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View("Logon");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("exception: {0}", ex.Message));
    Logging.WriteException(control, ex);
    return View("Logon");
  }
  finally
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "End Logon2");
    Logging.FlushLog(control);
  }
}
```

Both of the redirecttoactions are sending me to the default page. I put a debug on those lines and they are being reached but I'm always ending back up on my default page.

This is in my Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute("UnhandledExceptions", "Error", new {controller = "Error", action = "Index"});
  routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Account", action = "Logon", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();    
  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);      
}
```

This class has not changed. I'm getting no error messages that I can see. I stepped in and ended right back at my login method.

I'm not sure what is going on.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT 2**

My logon method if it helps any:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string id)
{
  var control = Logging.StartLog();
  control.ClassName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

  try
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "Starting LogOn");
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "id: " + id);

    CurrentCustomerSession.Current.SessionId = Session.SessionID;

    // set to expired if the session has timed out
    if (id == "expired")
    {
      const string msg = "Your session has expired. Please log back in if you wish to continue.";
      Logging.WriteLog(control, "Message given: " + msg);

      CurrentCustomerSession.Current.LoginMessage = msg;
      id = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
      CurrentCustomerSession.Current.LoginMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    // we are no longer relying on cookies since a customer could be
    // coming from one company to another such as Wells to Western States 
    Guid nid;
    if (!Guid.TryParse(id, out nid))
    {
      if (CurrentCustomerSession.Current.TokenId == Guid.Empty)
      {
        // if it failed in any of the checks then we give an invalid token page
        Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("TokenId check failed for: [{0}]", id));
        return View("InvalidToken");
      }            
    }

    // we've made it this far that means we have a tokenid
    if (nid != Guid.Empty)
    {
      CurrentCustomerSession.Current.TokenId = nid;
    }

    RecordVisitorInfo.Record(Request, nid);

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Logging.WriteLog(control, "Starting LogOff");
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Logging.WriteLog(control, "Signed Out");
    }
    return View();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.WriteException(control, ex);
    Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("exception: {0}", ex.Message));
    return View("Error");
  }
  finally
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "End Logon");
    Logging.FlushLog(control);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put on the address bar the url of any of the actions that are not working when redirecting? Are you also redirected to default or you see the correct page?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi very good question! Let me check.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I end up back at the login view:  /Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fCustomer%2fAccountScreen and I never reached my breakpoint in AccountScreen. :(

Comment: that means you're not logged in. Is your login logic working properly? You won't be able to access a protected page without being logged in

Comment: Both your actions, i.e., Logon and Logon2, are redirecting the users to Logon view only. Also, in Logon action you are signing off the users, which I believe should redirect you to Logon page only. Also, your default route is set to redirect to Logon action (and so Logon view effectively). Why do you expect it to redirect to Default page?

Comment: @ErocM I'm assuming your Customer controller (or some of its methods) has the `Authorize` attribute on it. When you're not logged in, by default you will be redirected to the login page with the ReturnUrl pointing to the page where you want to go after you successfully log in. If you want to test your redirect behavior, remove the Authorize attribute. A permanent fix would be to get your login working properly and handle logic where people aren't logged in. Also I'd debug your LogOn method to make sure you're actually logging in.

Comment: @TheWaywardRaven Yes they do and that is it. Tyvm all for the help!